# How to write into excel sheet using java by creating dynamic web project

Tags: java, excel

I want to insert data from a database to specified excel sheet cells. I have tried many type of code but didn't get solution.

My code is not working in Dynamic web project but it is working in normal java project. So please let me know how to insert and read from the excel sheet in dynamic web project.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please first try to implement it on your own and if you are stuck anywhere then you can put your questions here. And for Excel writing, you can refer https://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jExcelApi of java for reading/writing in excel file.
check following link http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/package-summary.html

First we need to create object reference of workbook then sheet then cell and then write data in cell.

Refer this link 
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=jxl.write.WritableWorkbook&method=createSheet
for example

May this links useful for you.